# How to modify non-configurable, non-writable properties in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

I'm writing a simple EventEmitter is ES5.

The objective is to ensure that all properties on `EventEmitter` instances are
non-writable and non-configurable."

After 6 hours of racking my brain I still can't figure out how to, increase the `listenerCount`, for example if the `configurable` descriptor is set to `false`.

Here's an example of what I have:

```
var eventEmitter = function(){
  var listeners = listeners || 0;
  var events = events || {};

  Object.defineProperties(this, {
   listeners: {
    value : 0,
    configurable: false,
    writable: false
  },
  events: {
    value: {},
    configurable : false,
    writable: false
    }
  });
  return this;
};


eventEmmitter.prototype.on = function(ev, cb) {
  if (typeof ev !== 'string') throw new TypeError("Event should be type string", "index.js", 6);
  if (typeof cb !== 'function' || cb === null || cb === undefined) throw new TypeError("callback should be type function", "index.js", 7);

  if (this.events[ev]){
    this.events[ev].push(cb);
  } else {
    this.events[ev] = [cb];
  }

  this.listeners ++;
  return this;
};
```

Comment: You… don't modify them?

Comment: What exactly is the requirement? You can use local variables and getter methods, or maybe getter properties as a workaround.

Comment: @Sua, Please add an update.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the use of an IIFE (immediatly invoked function expression):

```
var coolObj=(function(){
var public={};
var nonpublic={};
nonpublic.a=0;
public.getA=function(){nonpublic.a++;return nonpublic.a;};

return public;
})();
```

Now you can do:

```
coolObj.getA();//1
coolObj.getA();//2
coolObj.a;//undefined
coolObj.nonpublic;//undefined
coolObj.nonpublic.a;//undefined
```

I know this is not the answer youve expected, but i think its the easiest way of doing sth like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a proxy which requires a key in order to define properties:

```js
function createObject() {
  var key = {configurable: true};
  return [new Proxy({}, {
    defineProperty(target, prop, desc) {
      if (desc.value === key) {
        return Reflect.defineProperty(target, prop, key);
      }
    }
  }), key];
}
function func() {
  var [obj, key] = createObject();
  key.value = 0;
  Reflect.defineProperty(obj, "value", {value: key});
  key.value = function() {
    key.value = obj.value + 1;
    Reflect.defineProperty(obj, "value", {value: key});
  };
  Reflect.defineProperty(obj, "increase", {value: key});
  return obj;
}
var obj = func();
console.log(obj.value); // 0
try { obj.value = 123; } catch(err) {}
try { Object.defineProperty(obj, "value", {value: 123}); } catch(err) {}
console.log(obj.value); // 0
obj.increase();
console.log(obj.value); // 1
```